# How can I render a dynamic price based on some select options in nexts js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I have 2 different select tags with some options and I am rendering different images based on the selection and I would like to render down there a different price based on the options. For example: If I select the "Your Current Division" option to Iron and "Your Desire League" to Bronze/Silver/Gold I want the price to change. For the images I am hard coding some if's to check what the selected options are.

```html
<div className="text-gray-500 mt-7">
  <select name="divisions" onChange={slbz2} id="listt" className="bg-gray-200 pr-14 pl-2 py-2">
    <option value="ironn">Iron</option>
    <option value="bronze">Bronze</option>
    <option value="silverr">Silver</option>
    <option value="goldd">Gold</option>
    <option value="platt">Platinum</option>
    <option value="diaa">Diamond</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div className="mt-5">
  <select name="divisions" onChange={slbz2} id="tierr" className="bg-gray-200 pr-12 pl-2 py-2">
    <option value="44">Division IV</option>
    <option value="33">Division III</option>
    <option value="22">Division II</option>
    <option value="11">Division I</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

[and some conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfhqo.png)

Here you can see a demo: https://elowish-2.vercel.app/pricing

Answer (score 0):

In such scenarios, `useEffect()` is very helpful.
Refer -> [ReactJS Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Assuming `state1` as the state variable for "Your Current Division".
and `state2` as the state variable for "Your Desire League".

use `state1` and `state2` inside dependency array of useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Update your final state accordingly
}, [state1, state2]);
```

**Update 1:**
After looking at your conditions screenshot, It looks like you're not using useState [Please refer Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Comment: How can I target different options with the states? I am kinda new, I am using state just to set the image based on the if's as you can see in my screenshot.